# How to add 1 to previous data if NaN in pandas

Tags: pandas, fillna

I was wondering if it is possible to add 1 (or n) to missing values in a pandas DataFrame / Series.

For example:
1
10
**nan**
15
25
**nan**
**nan**
**nan**
30

Would return :
1
10
**11**
15
25
**26**
**27**
**28**
30

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ffill` + the result of a `groupby.cumcount` to determine `n`

```
df[0].ffill() + df.groupby(df[0].notnull().cumsum()).cumcount()

0     1.0
1    10.0
2    11.0
3    15.0
4    25.0
5    26.0
6    27.0
7    28.0
8    30.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Also, do you know how to use this if the data is in a DataFrame and not a Serie (I cant groupby in 2-dimension).  I am thinking of unstacking and adding the columns in the groupby then pivoting back to the DF, but the DF is massive so it takes quite some time

Comment: @Youpi14 I can't imagine that problem. Either edit your question to reflect the new issue, or if it is different enough you should ask another question. Either way, you should provide a [mcve] that represents your real problem and the expected output, otherwise you'll continue to get solutions that don't solve your actual problem.